# VS 2022. ASP.NET Core with Angular. Opening multiple ng serve consoles when ClientApp fails

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

#### Describe

Created a new SP.NET Core with Angular project. in VS 2022 (Version 17.6.2)
I need the project to run under the iis virtual directory VirDir.
i tried to configure this behavior through `angular.json` file by writing baseHref

```
{
   "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
   version: 1
   "newProjectRoot": "projects",
   projects: {
     "Project2": {
       "projectType": "application",
       "schematics": {
         "@schematics/angular:application": {
           "strict": true
         }
       },
       root: "",
       "sourceRoot": "src",
       "prefix": "app",
       "architecture": {
         build: {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
           "options": {
             "progress": false
             "baseHref": "/VirDir"
```

and it works
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/assets/51095170/89f5e90a-daf1-4792-aed7-934ddff470ed

but if there is an error in the ClientApp, after a while, another window opens for me

```
> project2@0.0.0 start
> ng serve --port 44425

? Port 44425 is already in use.
Would you like to use a different port? (Y/n)
```

The question, is whether I have correctly configured the project to work with the virtual directory, and how to disable the re-opening of the window?

```
> project2@0.0.0 start
> ng serve --port 44425

? Port 44425 is already in use.
Would you like to use a different port? (Y/n)
```

because if there is an error in the ClientApp project that I know about, then after a while I have a lot of these windows, which interferes.
For example, I launched a project, with an error, got distracted, for example, by a call, then after 10 minutes I already have 10 open windows...
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/assets/51095170/13d38c99-a0d4-4f45-9935-055e3819d07e

#### .NET Version

7.0.302

#### Steps To Reproduce

create a new project asp core with angular, write baseHref in `angular.json` , for example
`"baseHref": "/VirDir"`
And make an error in ClientApp in any file and after some time you will get

```
> project2@0.0.0 start
> ng serve --port 44425

? Port 44425 is already in use.
Would you like to use a different port? (Y/n)
```

and then again, then again

#### Expected Behavior

single window ng serve

Comment: noted that this behavior does not depend on baseHref.